# Post finished layout of inflation

Tags: android, android-layout

I inflate my custom-classed-layout but I can't access `findViewById` on `this` inside the constructor because the fields don't exist yet.

I can't use `onLayout` because `onLayout` is called whenever children are added/removed so my code runs multiple times when I only want it to run once.

I tried `onLayoutFinished`, but that doesn't always work.

I would like to leverage something like a `onInitialLayoutFinished` which of course isn't a real system function. What should I be using here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onLayoutFinished` method doesn't exist. You have to Override `onFinishInflate`:

```
    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();    
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    }
```

[DOC](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onFinishInflate%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

@Override

```
protected void onFinishInflate()

{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onFinishInflate();
}
```